# How to distribute a j2ee application on multiple servers?

Tags: java, performance, deployment, jakarta-ee, distribution

I'm using JSP+Struts2+Tomcat6+Hibernate+MySQL as my J2EE developing environment. Due to the project's large scale and upcoming performance issues, it's been decided to deploy the project on multiple servers. 
Since the project has been developed in 3-tier architecture, we wanna dedicate a separated machines to each tier and connect them via GigaBit Ethenrnet connections. So we're gonna need a DB-Server(MySQL), a Logic-Server(Struts2+POJOs) and a Web-Server.

I suppose the communication between DB-Server and Logic-Server wouldn't be a problem but connecting the web-server and the Logic-Server seems kinda baffling to me. Considering the fact that we might increase the number of server machines of each tier in the next phases, what are my options in this situation?

Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

[EDIT]

Tomcat is a part of the Logic-Server and it lies where POJOs and struts go, What I mean by web-server is a front end server which takes users' requests and dispatches them to the Logic-Server.
On the other hand we might wanna use more than one Logic-Server. Is it even possible?

By the way, would JMS be any help here?

Answer (score 1):

The logic needs to go on the Tomcat server as well. Struts without a web server makes no sense.

Or did you mean "Web server" as in "dumb file server that understands HTTP"? In that case, you don't connect them at all; the web browser will do that for you: The JSP/Servlet code will send URLs for the images and other static content to the browser and the browser will use those URLs to download the data directly from the "web server".

You definitely don't want the "Logic server" download the stuff and serve it as well.

Comment: @Aaaron: You're definitely right about tomcat, I edited the question to keep away the next viewers from getting the wrong idea. I think I'm gonna agree with you on the "dumb file server that understands HTTP". so what goes on this one? just the JSP pages? could you explain your idea in more details?

Comment: The dump HTTP server serves CSS, static javascript (not the parts that you generate in JSPs), images, logos, anything that isn't generated. the JSPs go on the logic server together with the POJOs.

Comment: thank buddy, seems plausible but a little bit troublesome regarding to JSP pages I have. I'll take it into more consideration

Answer (score 1):

Can you even split up a Struts application into a "Logic Server" and a Web Server?

Tomcat is an application server, because it can run your logic and serve your pages.
If you really want to distribute your logic-running load onto another server, try implementing a Service Oriented Architecture.

My experience is limited to using: JSF for front end and some date manipulation (for presentation), IBM Websphere for the logic (the processes are designed in Websphere Integration Developer, not pure Java), and Oracle for the DB. All of these servers are hosted on separate machines.

In your case, you can use a Java web-application to execute your logic, and it can run on another Tomcat server (separate from your front-end application's server). In this case, you will expose your functions as webservices and let the front-end application invoke them.

Comment: Salam, I think you're right, separating tomcat and POJOs isn't even possible, I got confused for a moment! I edited the question. you might wanna reconsider the last part.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by taking requests and dispatching them to the server. Does it mean you want a  form page (front end) that POSTS or GETS data to a java class (logic layer) that inserts it into the DB (Data layer)? In this case, it would not make sense to have them on different servers. However, if you significant load of server based processing for the front end (after your core logic has run and returned the data), you can keep them on different servers.

Comment: you got it. that's what I'm thinking of. A front end Server which POSTs and GETs (executes actions) data to java classes (logic layer) and the logic layer communicates with a separated DB layer. Since there will be plenty of users and way lots of requests, it'd better to manage them on a separated front end server and alleviate the load of logic server. still disagree?

Comment: Agreed. Your servlets will receive the POSTS and GETS and you can keep them on another server. I'm not sure how much of Struts would survive this split.

Answer (score 0):

Distributing the application according to the tiers is not necessarily a good idea. Network communication is slow compared to communication within a single JVM. For this reason, you want to minimize the communication between the separate machines. This is usually achieved by providing a coarse grained interfaces, e.g.

```
interface User
{
  void setAddress(String name,
                  String street,
                  String zip,
                  String city,
                  String country);
}
```

instead of

```
interface User
{
  void setName(String name);
  void setStreet(String street);
  void setZip(String zip);
  void setCity(String city);
  void setCountry(String country);
}
```

The rational is, that if you change one piece of information in a `User` object, other pieces are likely to be changed as well. The coarse grained interface then ensures fewer method invocations over the network.

Comment: -1 Methods with more than four parameters are brittle, hard to test and bad style. Plus the answer is unrelated to the question. :-)

Comment: @Aaron The *four* you mention is arbitrary. Other sources say six. Plus the answer is related to the question, because it tells what needs to be considered when distributing a j2ee application on multiple servers. Your -1 would have been justified if you would have reasoned that coarse grained interfaces do not need to be considered when when distributing a j2ee application on multiple servers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but using coarse grained interfaces wouldn't be a plausible option because first it demands lots of change in the code and second hibernate won't take it so friendly.

Comment: @SJ.Jafari: Coarse grained interfaces do not replace fine grains ones. They supplement them. They are specifically used for transferring data across machines. See [P of EAA: Remote Facade](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/remoteFacade.html) and [Core J2EE Patterns: Transfer Object](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/TransferObject.html) for details.

Comment: Interesting, I'll take them into consideration.